# Eclipse debugger stops on equivalent location at old project instead of actual breakpoint location at new project

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jboss, jboss7.x, breakpoints

I have two web projects, A and B, in the same workspace, that most of their packages and classes are similar.

(I deploy my war files to Jboss).

I've set a breakpoint at some class of project B. However when the debugger (eclipse) stops on that breakpoint, it does it at the same location (at least regarding the line number) at the equivalent class of project A.

Why is this happening, and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same class names in both projects, JBoss will load and only use the first one encountered

Comment: These are two separated projects. I don't deploy both projects to Jboss, only project B. And even if I did, a project is not supposed to be aware of what happens within other projects.

Comment: Do you deploy through eclipse or do you build a jar and then place it in the war directory?

Comment: B is a maven project. I build with maven, and during `mvn install` I deploy to Jboss by the maven plugin `jboss-as-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Can you try to deploy using eclipse's export as well as wipe any other war files you have on jboss? Also do both classes contain the same names?

Comment: Sounds to me like an issue with eclipse debugger, not how I deploy the project. There's no remnant of project A in Jboss. So how would eclipse be bothered by the method I used for deployment. I don't know what you mean by deploy using eclipse's export. AFAIK, eclipse's export is to build a war, but not to deploy. But I have the war, through maven, which I can deploy to jboss manually, or by the jboss eclipse plugin.

Comment: My best guesses are these: 1 - Eclipse has two same-uri classes (com.this.class repeated twice in your IDE) and it can't figure out which one to associate with your debug session. 2 - You have the wrong WAR deployed. I know it may sound far-fetched but I've ran into this problem with various teams more times than I'd be willing to admit. 3 - You did not setup your debug connection for that profile correctly. Without further info, it's hard to tell which one it is.

Comment: I just re-built with maven and deployed manually to a clean Jboss, then restarted Jboss in debug and got the same problem. To refer to your guesses: 1. It does have the same classes within the same packages, as I explained, but in DIFFERENT PROJECTS in the same workspace. So how do I make eclipse figure this out is my question. 2. I manually deployed the correct war. 3. What is profile and what do I need to set about debug? I restart Jboss from eclipse's servers view: restart in debug. That always work, and still works for other projects in my workspace.

Comment: If I add to a class at project B some output lines for debugging purposes, executing the class in the debugger editor goes to the right line number, but in the equivalent (wrong) class at project A. As I step over lines in the class, output lines start being printed to console (correctly). Although the class that Eclipse shows me in the editor has no output lines!

Comment: Can you try closing your irrelevant project while debugging? Also, what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Do you mean, deleting project A from the workspace? I use Eclipse Juno.